# How to sort a pair of keys and values using boost?

Tags: c++, sorting, boost

Is there some function in boost library which can sort key-value pairs?

e.g. keys being an array of double variables, and values are some index (integer) of the array.

Comment: Before you get help, be more specific, sort by what? What sort function have you tried?

Comment: Probably not; Boost wouldn't duplicate `std::sort`.

Comment: I don't get the question. Are you trying to sort a vector of pairs ?
or just values associated with keys-map ?

Answer (score 1):

What you probably want is a `std::map<My_Double_Array, size_t>` along with your own `My_Double_Array` class that wraps your array of `double` variables and provides a `operator <()` for sorting.  Or simply `std::map<std::vector<double>, size_t>` might be all you need.